# Gcloud error - ssh key for Gcloud does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, gcloud-cli

[error in gcloud cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTutq.png)

I am trying to upload the review.csv file from my local file system to hdfs using gcloud compute scp command but it is showing the error as follows--

C:\Users\DELL\Downloads>gcloud compute scp Reviews.csv girishratnaparkhi04@hadoop-cluster-m:/home/girishratnaparkhi04
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist. WARNING: The PuTTY PPK SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
This tool needs to create the directory [C:\Users\DELL.ssh] before being able to generate SSH keys.
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?

how to solve this ?

I have restarted the cluster and tried multiple times

Comment: Let the CLI create a key. Edit your post with more details such as the SSH key history, the VM you are trying to access, and why you are concerned. As written, we don't know why you have a problem.